# Hovering over an element to be displayed on all client applications

Tags: html, css, vue.js, client

I'm currently having an application which highlights certain areas when you hover over them or click. It works fine but I'd like the hovering and active clicking to be displayed on every client (note that every client has an identic overlay).
It might be bad practice but what I did was to configurate the span-tag (I only use it once for the elements I want to be highlighted), see the following code:

```css
      span {
          border-color: transparent;
          border-style: dashed;
          border-width: 1.5px;
      }
      span:hover {
          background: rgb(255, 255, 000, 0.5);
          border-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
          border-style: dashed;
          border-width: 1.5px;
          border-radius: 100%
      }
      span:active {
          background:rgb(255, 185, 015, 0.5);
          border-color: rgb(47, 47, 47);
          border-style: dashed;
          border-width: 1.5px
      }
```

```html
                      <span class="switch" @click="onSwitchClick(key)"></span>
```

This snippet does not work here.

Anyone having an idea? And also recommendations on how to improve my implementation?
Usually I would have defined a class and added
myClass:hover and active too, but since I'm using Vue.js and the setup is a bit differently, I used some workarounds (noob in vue). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It has no width, specify it and/or add `display: block` to your `span`